# transfer app from thumb drive to Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: synchronization, samsung-smart-tv

Is there a way to transfer an app from a thumb drive to a Samsung Smart TV? Currently I am using the app sync function to get the app that I am developing onto the Smart TV, but I would also like to be able to use a thumb drive so I can test on other TVs without having to sync with my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I've succeed on 2012 (E) Series Device with this method:

1. Unzip your packaged apps to the a folder on root path of thumbdrive (F:/MyApps/)
2. Put your thumbdrive to device
3. Power off TV then Power On again
4. Your apps should be available on Smart Hub